# Dynamic Session Variable Store (Table Doesn't work on 3rd Try)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, textbox

I got the code from someone before and adapted it to my own liking.  However, I may be misinterpreting their code, but on the 3rd click of the button the table gets all out of wack.  I'm making a dynamic textbox with table and saving it to session after every click of the "Click here to add an accident".

2nd Click:

[image: 2nd Click]

3rd Click:

[image: 3rd Click]

I've tried debugging it and it just doesn't make sense to why it would do this.  My code is correct I believe, I'm not sure what is going wrong.

```
public partial class employment_driversapplication_History : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}

protected int TotalNumberAdded
{
    get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }


}



protected void AccidentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TotalNumberAdded++;
   // AddControls(TotalNumberAdded);
    BuildControls();


}
protected void PrevPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect("employment_driversapplication_personalinfo.aspx");

}

private IList<TextBox> AddedControls = new List<TextBox>();
private IList<Label> AddedControlsLabel = new List<Label>();
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    BuildControls();
    base.CreateChildControls();
}

private void BuildControls()
{






    AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table><tr>"));
    AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

    for (var Nl = 0; Nl < TotalNumberAdded; Nl++)
    {
        var idNL = String.Format("NatureLabel{0}", Nl);


        //Check if control was already added 
        //only create controls that are new for this postback
        if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(idNL) == null)
        {
            var NLabel = new Label() { ID = idNL };
            NLabel.Text = "Nature Of Accident: ";
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td class='title-text'>"));
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(NLabel);

            AddedControlsLabel.Add(NLabel);

        }
    }




    for (var x = 0; x < TotalNumberAdded; x++)
    {
        var idN = String.Format("NatureTextBox{0}", x);

        //Check if control was already added 
        //only create controls that are new for this postback
        if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(idN) == null)
        {
            var NtextBox = new TextBox() { ID = idN };

            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'width='180px'>"));
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(NtextBox);

            AddedControls.Add(NtextBox);

        }
    }

    for (var DL = 0; DL < TotalNumberAdded; DL++)
    {
        var idDL = String.Format("DateLabel{0}", DL);


        //Check if control was already added 
        //only create controls that are new for this postback
        if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(idDL) == null)
        {
            var DLabel = new Label() { ID = idDL };
            DLabel.Text = "Date: ";
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(DLabel);

            AddedControlsLabel.Add(DLabel);

        }
    }


    for (var d = 0; d < TotalNumberAdded; d++)
    {
        var idD = String.Format("DateTextBox{0}", d);
        if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(idD) == null)
        {

            var DtextBox = new TextBox() { ID = idD };

            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'width='180px'>"));
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(DtextBox);
            AddedControls.Add(DtextBox);
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));

        }


    }

    for (var FL = 0; FL < TotalNumberAdded; FL++)
    {
        var idFL = String.Format("FatalLabel{0}", FL);


        //Check if control was already added 
        //only create controls that are new for this postback
        if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(idFL) == null)
        {
            var FLabel = new Label() { ID = idFL };
            FLabel.Text = "Fatalities: ";
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td class='title-text'>"));
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(FLabel);

            AddedControlsLabel.Add(FLabel);

        }
    }
    for (var f = 0; f < TotalNumberAdded; f++)
    {
        var idF = String.Format("FatalTextBox{0}", f);
        if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(idF) == null)
        {

            var FtextBox = new TextBox() { ID = idF };
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'width='180px'>"));
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(FtextBox);
            AddedControls.Add(FtextBox);


        }


    }

    for (var IL = 0; IL < TotalNumberAdded; IL++)
    {
        var idIL = String.Format("InjuryLabel{0}", IL);


        //Check if control was already added 
        //only create controls that are new for this postback
        if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(idIL) == null)
        {
            var ILabel = new Label() { ID = idIL };
            ILabel.Text = "Injuries: ";
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'>"));
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ILabel);

            AddedControlsLabel.Add(ILabel);

        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded; i++)
    {
        var idI = String.Format("InjuryTextBox{0}", i);
        if (AccidentPlaceHolder.FindControl(idI) == null)
        {

            var ItextBox = new TextBox() { ID = idI };

            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td class='title-text'width='180px'>"));
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ItextBox);
            AddedControls.Add(ItextBox);
            AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));

        }


    }
    AccidentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table>"));
}

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var ctrl in AddedControls)
    {
        var key = ctrl.ID.Replace("TextBox", String.Empty);
        Session[key] = ctrl.Text;
    }

    foreach (string session in Session.Keys)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", session, Session[session]));
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}

}
```

Any Help would be appreciated... I've been looking and debugging it for a few hours and nothing has fixed it.

Comment: yeah i'm new to the site...didn't know about the whole accept and not accept till a little bit ago.. sorry :(

Comment: if i could i would give many many points to everyone who participates :)

Comment: also i did what you recommended...and it seems to be putting the first two "tables" into one so basically the </table> tag is not being implemented but i'm trying to figure out why

Comment: fair enough :) Thanks for acknowledging. BTW, you can go back and still accept answers...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implementing a repeater for this? It would be a lot easier that adding literal controls, as it can quickly get out of hand and makes it more difficult to debug.

One of the uses of a repeater control is to repeat an output of html for each data item. In your case you would repeat the output of the table for each accident.

For example, this would be your code on the front-end:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAccidents" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="title-text">
                    Nature Of Accident
                </td>
                <td class='title-text' width='180px'>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNature" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td class="title-text">
                    Date
                </td>
                <td class='title-text' width='180px'>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            ....NEXT ROWS
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <br />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And this would be in your code-behind:

```
    //HERE YOU ARE ATTACHING TO THE REPEATER'S ITEMDATABOUND EVENT
    //THIS ALLOWS YOU TO CONTROL THE OUTPUT FOR EACH ACCIDENT
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        this.rptAccidents.ItemDataBound += rptAccidents_ItemDataBound;
    }

    //THIS IS THE CODE THAT WILL RUN FOR EACH DATA ITEM IN THE REPEATER'S DATA SOURCE
    void rptAccidents_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //in this case, you only care about the item templates
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            //cast your dataitem here
            Accident data = (Accident)data;
            //find the appropriate textbox (or any other control that is runat="server", and set the value.
            ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtNature")).Text = data.Nature;
            ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtDate")).Text = data.Date;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.rptAccidents.DataSource = //I AM NOT SURE WHERE YOU ARE STORING THE DATA. BUT HERE IS WHERE YOU WOULD SET THE REPEATERS DATA SOURCE
            this.rptAccidents.DataBind(); //THIS LINE CAUSES THE REPEAT TO BIND ITSELF TO YOUR DATA SOURCE
        }
    }
```

Comment: I started out in HTML, then learned a bit of C#, then learned ASP.net.  A repeater meaning what like Table thistable = new Table(); and the whole row stuff? I realized that it is throwing the labels and texboxes into the same table a few times due to going through the for loop so many times, so i gotta figure out a way for it to separate them